# how to check if a link is a downloading file or a website in android webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

I use `webview` of android in my app, I'm wondering if there is a function in `webview` in which I can check that the opened link is file or a website page. for example if the link is for mp4 file I want to download the file otherwise load the url in `webview`. here is my download listener function:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadFileManager.getInstance().startDownload(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength);
        }
    });
```

this is the called function:

```
public void startDownload(String url, String userAgent,
                          String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                          long contentLength) {
    if (PermissionHelper.isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
        String fileName = FileNameGenerator.getUniqueNameForDownloadedFile(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
        long downloadManagerId = AndroidDownloadManagerHelper.downloadUrl(url, contentDisposition, mimetype, fileName);
        this.saveDownloadEntity(fileName, contentLength, downloadManagerId);
        this.runningDownloadItems.add(new DownloadItem(downloadManagerId));
        this.startDownloadProgressJob();
    }
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: You cannot load an mp4 file in a WebView.

Comment: @blackapps presumably that's why they want to download it instead

Comment: @Ryan M, yes. And that is what will happen instead automatically.

Comment: it will not happen automatically for me. I don't know what I did wrong but the download function does not get called when I click in mp4 file url!